# Why does P4Python not recognize P4CONFIG setting?

Tags: python, linux, perforce, p4python

I have the following code:

```
# script0.py
def main():
    p4 = p4python.P4.P4()
    p4.connect()
    print os.environ['P4CONFIG']
    print p4.p4config_file
    p4.disconnect()
```

which is being called via:

```
# script0_test.py
subprocess.check_call(['script0.py'])
```

and is outputting:

```
.p4config
noconfig
```

When script0.py is called from the command line or if subprocess.check_call(shell=True) is used, it outputs correct info:

```
.p4config
/home/nyap/proj/.p4config
```

Why does the p4 object not recognize the P4CONFIG setting when shell=False?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue. It appears to be a bug in P4Python specific to Linux.
The P4 class is being intialized with the current working directory set to '/' instead of the actual working directory. This then stops P4 from finding the .p4config file.

The following workaround fixed it for me:

```
  p4 = P4.P4(cwd=os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 0):

From a command-line, what does `p4 set` show for P4CONFIG? If it's not there, then you'll need to do `p4 set P4CONFIG=".p4config"` (on Windows or OS X). If your `p4 set` output already lists P4CONFIG then I don't know... If you're on Linux, the [p4 set manpage](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/set.html) says it will show the corresponding environment variables but you can't set them that way. In that case, I dunno.

Comment: Yes. Why would the OS matter considering os.environ['P4CONFIG'] is saying that P4CONFIG is set?

Comment: Because on the other OS's Perforce doesn't look at the environment variables first. It looks at it's own copies (in the registry on Windows, for example). That's why the OS matters. [edit: upon reading the manpage more closely, the environment variables are examined]